# Error when converting between Double and Int

Tags: swift

I've come across an error when converting `Int.max` to a double then back to integer:

```
print(Int(Double(Int.max)))
```

and getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max

I'd be appreciated if you can explain me the the reason of the above error. 
Is it something related to [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)?

Tested this on Swift 4.2.

Comment: I think above 2^53 you won't be ale to represent every integer value using a Double `Int(pow(2.0,54.0)+2) ==
Int(pow(2.0,54.0))` returns true. If you try `Int(pow(2.0,53.0)+2) ==
Int(pow(2.0,53.0))` returns false as expected